# How to calculate a percentile ranking of a column of data relative to another column using python

Tags: python, pandas, quantile, percentile

I have two columns of data representing the same quantity; one column is from my training data, the other is from my validation data.

I know how to calculate the percentile rankings of the training data efficiently using:

```
pandas.DataFrame(training_data).rank(pct = True).values
```

My question is, how can I *efficiently* get a similar set of percentile rankings of the validation data column *relative* to the training data column? That is, for each value in the validation data column, how can I find what its percentile ranking would be relative to all the values in the training data column?

I've tried doing this:

```
def percentrank(input_data,comparison_data):
    rescaled_data = np.zeros(input_data.size)
    for idx,datum in enumerate(input_data):
        rescaled_data[idx] =scipy.stats.percentileofscore(comparison_data,datum)
    return rescaled_data/100
```

But I'm not sure if this is even correct, and on top of that it's incredibly slow because it is doing a lot of redundant calculations for each value in the for loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a solution.
Sort the training data. Then use searchsorted on the validation data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate Dummy Data
df_train = pd.DataFrame({'Values': 1000*np.random.rand(15712)})

#Sort Data
df_train = df_train.sort_values('Values')

# Calculating Rank and Rank_Pct for demo purposes 
#but note that it is not needed for the solution
# The ranking of the validation data below does not depend on this
df_train['Rank'] = df_train.rank()
df_train['Rank_Pct']= df_train.Values.rank(pct=True)

# Demonstrate how Rank Percentile is calculated
# This gives the same value as .rank(pct=True)
pct_increment = 1./len(df_train)
df_train['Rank_Pct_Manual'] = df_train.Rank*pct_increment

df_train.head()

       Values  Rank  Rank_Pct  Rank_Pct_Manual
2724  0.006174   1.0  0.000064         0.000064
3582  0.016264   2.0  0.000127         0.000127
5534  0.095691   3.0  0.000191         0.000191
944   0.141442   4.0  0.000255         0.000255
7566  0.161766   5.0  0.000318         0.000318
```

Now use searchsorted to get Rank_Pct of validation data

```
# Generate Dummy Validation Data
df_validation = pd.DataFrame({'Values': 1000*np.random.rand(1000)})

# Note searchsorted returns array index. 
# In sorted list rank is the same as the array index +1
df_validation['Rank_Pct'] = (1 + df_train.Values.searchsorted(df_validation.Values))*pct_increment
```

Here is first few lines of final df_validation dataframe:

```
print df_validation.head()
      Values  Rank_Pct
0  307.378334  0.304290
1  744.247034  0.744208
2  669.223821  0.670825
3  149.797030  0.145621
4  317.742713  0.314218
```

Answer (score 5):

A small improvement to the nice solution above is to average the positions found by searching from the left and searching from the right:

```
df_validation['Rank_Pct'] = (0.5 + 0.5*df_train.Values.searchsorted(df_validation.Values, side='left') + 0.5*df_train.Values.searchsorted(df_validation.Values, side='right'))*pct_increment
```

This change is important in cases where a value occurs multiple times. Consider searching for 2 in [1,2,2,2,4] - searching from the left gives 1, while search from the right gives 3. Averaging the two gives the same percentile ranking as the pandas .rank(pct=True) routine.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but here's a concise solution

```
from scipy import stats

training = pd.Series([64,63,67,69,67])
test = pd.Series([66,72])
training_percentiles = training.rank(pct=True) * 100
testing_percentiles = test.apply(lambda x: stats.percentileofscore(training, x))
```

training_percentiles:

```
0     40.0
1     20.0
2     70.0
3    100.0
4     70.0
```

testing_percentiles:

```
0     40.0
1    100.0
```

I've done this with series, but the same can be applied to DataFrames